# Dollar sign in URL breaks link

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

I've seen a number of reports of special characters breaking links, some of which seem to get fixes, others seem to be tagged "status-by-design".  I didn't see any indicating that the $ sign wasn't working so I thought I'd report it.  I tried to link to:

> http://c2.com/cgi/wiki$?VirtualPairProgramming

But the link does not appear as a link either in the editor or in the completed question.  I *fixed* it by using TinyURL to proxy the link and pasting in the TinyURL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See if you can safely remove the dollar sign (`$`)

> http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?VirtualPairProgramming

The [dollar sign is a special character](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) (and apparently hasn't been taken in with the automatic SO linkifier).

If you wanted (or could be bothered) you can also encode to its hex equivalent (`%24`):

> http://c2.com/cgi/wiki%24?VirtualPairProgramming

Comment: Never even occurred to me to remove it.  I'd been hit with something similar before so I immediately went to my fallback of TinyURL.

Answer (score 0):

Must be escaped; nice that it happens to be optional in this case.

**Edit:** Note that [as of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), problem characters will automatically be escaped when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L).

Comment: The RFC for URLs says that this character is one that does NOT need to be escaped, like the character used for escaping, or pluses. Therefore, breaking your URL parsing on a dollar sign is a bug. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: @DanGrossman: This has nothing to do with RFC. We're talking about *auto* -recognizing links in text; you need some trade-offs there.

Comment: Is there any way we could parse all questions for links, and automatically escape the $? I came across this in another post again, and removing the $ is not a working solution, although it looks like escaping it manually does work (in the browser URL field that is, didn't make the change to the question).