# Period in Tag/URL breaks page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config)

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config

[image]

I am sorry if this has been found before, I didn't see anything when I searched for it.

Similiar to this post, but not quite : [Dollar sign in URL breaks link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/dollar-sign-in-url-breaks-link)

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config

Periods are filtered out, most likely `[by-design]`.